# Handling stereo sound in pascal

Tags: audio, pascal

I am creating top down game in Pascal for which I want positional sounds.  To do this I was going to pass a sound file set at different volumes through each speaker individually, and was going to change the values for the volume as the sound creating object moved around.

However, I cannot find a way to do this, so my question is, is this possible?  If yes, how would you go about it?  If no, could you show me a more sensible way to control the positional sounds for the game?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pascal the language? What platform? In any case - OpenAL is probably where you want to start although you may not be able to use Pascal with it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL